# Let $g$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with certain conditions. Show that $g(x) = x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, riemann-integration

Let $g$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ s.t.
$$\int_{0}^{1} g^2(x) dx = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} xg(x)dx = \frac{1}{3}$$

Show that $g(x) = x \forall x \in [0,1]$.

My work so far.
I wrote it as
$$\int_{0}^{1} (g^2(x) - xg(x))dx = 0$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1} (xg(x) - g^2(x)) dx = 0$$

So, if one of these is negative, then the other must be positive. I know that if integral of a non-negative function is $0$, then the function is $0$. However, I am not quite sure how to show that the function is non-negative. In fact I'm not even convinced it has to be. I believe this could work if the function is $g(x) = -x$. I must be forgetting an important property here since I'm not seeing it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $$\int_0^1g^2(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{3};\quad \int_0^1g(x)\cdot x dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\Longrightarrow\int_0^12g(x)\cdot x dx=\dfrac{2}{3};\quad \int_0^1x^2dx=\dfrac{1}{3}.$$ Then $$\int_0^1\underbrace{g^2(x)-2xg(x)+x^2}_{(g(x)-x)^2}dx=0\Longrightarrow\int_0^1(g(x)-x)^2dx=0.$$ Since $(g(x)-x)^2$ is a positive function whose integral is equal to $0$, then we conclude that $$g(x)-x=0\quad a.e. x\in[0,1]\Longrightarrow g(x)=x\quad a.e. x\in[0,1].$$ Finally, thanks to $g$ being continous, we get that $$g(x)=x\quad \forall x\in[0,1].$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining why we're examining $(g(x) - x)^2$. Now I see where it comes from! Thank you!

Comment: @DominicBlanco You are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $(g(x)-x)^2\geq 0$ for all $x$, so:\begin{align}0&\leq \int_{0}^{1} (g(x)-x)^2 dx \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{1} g^2(x) dx-2\int_{0}^{1} xg(x) dx +\int_{0}^{1} x^2 dx \\&
= \frac{1}{3} -2\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{3}\\ &=0\end{align}

so $$\int_{0}^{1} (g(x)-x)^2 dx =0$$

so $g(x)=x$, for all $x$, since $x$ is continuous.

Comment: This isn't the right function. It's $\int_{0}^{1} (g^2(x) - xg(x) dx = 0$ or the subtraction flipped.

Comment: @DominicBlanco, what are you talking about?

Comment: @TonyK I read the answer below and it made sense. This post just uses $(g(x) - x)^2$ without explaining where it comes from. My functions are not of that form. They are $g^2(x) - xg(x)$ and $xg(x) - g^2(x)$. Without the context this didn't make sense.